# How to implement java android method Base64.encodeToString(); in php

Tags: java, php, android, string, base64

How to implement this *method* in **php** from **java android**:

```
Base64.encodeToString(aesDataJson.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `base64_encode()`. Take a look at official docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)